# How to switch Tabbed View in Unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Main Tab Bar Controller with 3 Views.

1. Main View
2. History View
3. Menu View

When my App first loads, the Tab Bar Controller checks if the user is Logged On, if she is not, it segues to a Logon view. Once the user Logs On I call an Unwind Segue from the Logon View as follows:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToTabBarFromSignInView", sender: self)
```

This brings the user to the Unwind Segue of the Menu View in my Tab Bar controller since this is the View with the Logout button, thus it was the View that was presented to the User last. However, I would like to present the Main View instead of the Menu View once the user Logs On. To accomplish this I have the following code in the Unwind Segue. Unfortunately, it seems to have no effect, the user keeps being brought back to the Menu View once they Log On instead of the Main View.

```
@IBAction func unwindToTabBarFromSignInView(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

Comment: Is `tabBarController` nil?

Comment: no, tabBarController isn't nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's curious that that doesn't work.  But I have an easier solution.

When unwinding to a `UITabBarController`, every tab's `ViewController` can implement its own unwind `@IBAction` and you can do directly to the tab you want.

In your `MainViewController` implement this:

```
@IBAction func unwindToMainViewController(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("back in MainViewController")
}
```

Create the unwind segue by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from the *ViewController* icon to the *Exit* icon and give it an identifier `"unwindToMain"`. Once the user logs on, simply call:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToMain", sender: self)
```

and you will return to the Main tab of your `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Thanks! of course that worked like a charm! I was so fixated in switching the tab I can't believe I didn't see how easy it could be.